# Serving a file efficiently using Play 2.3

Tags: file, scala, playframework

I need to serve some content from an Action in the form of a file: basically, I am creating CSV content on the fly and sending it to the client.

I cannot do it using sendFile, since the file does not really exist; I tried using the chunked transfer, but I get a really slow response (in localhost I got the file at about 100KB/s, which I think is really strange).

Is there a way for me to set the content type and write the response "line by line", without having to specify the content length "a priori"?

Comment: Is this for Java or Scala?

Comment: Scala! Sorry, I forgot to write it above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a simple predefined `Enumerator` that will produce the response from bytes written to an `OutputStream`:

```
def csv = Action {
    val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { out =>
       out.write(...)

       // Keep writing to the Enumerator

       out.close()
    }

    Ok.chunked(enumerator.andThen(Enumerator.eof)).withHeaders(
       "Content-Type" -> "text/csv", 
       "Content-Disposition" -> s"attachment; filename=test.csv"
    )
}
```

This is simple enough for relatively small files (or if the process of generating the file is slow by nature), however note that from the documentation this has no back-pressure, reading a large file into the `OutputStream` can quickly fill up memory if the client can't download it quickly enough.

**Update**:

After testing this some more it seems like the size of the `Byte` arrays you write to the `OutputStream` make a huge difference in throughput.

Using this sample stream:

```
val s = Stream.continually(0.toByte)
```

Writing in chunks of 1KB to the `OutputStream` like this resulted in 6MB/s of throughput:

```
(0 until 1024*1024).foreach{i =>
    out.write(s.take(1024).toArray)
}
```

However if I only write 10 bytes at a time, the throughput slows to less than 100KB/s. So my suggestion for using this method to write CSVs in a chunked form would be to write multiple rows at a time to the `OutputStream` rather than one row at a time.

Comment: I think I already tried this and for some reason it downloaded the file quite slowly... I will try it asap and add more comments.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just generating the file slowly? I've been able to serve large files like this very quickly.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it and the chunked response seems to be the slowest part: I am logging the moment immediately before closing the output stream, and it happens really fast, but then it takes 10 seconds for Play to send the resulting data to the client (1 MB @ 100 KB/s). Any idea?

Comment: @AlessandroSivieri I've updated my answer to include some new material that will probably solve your problem.